# Cannot get includes and joins to work in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I am building a Rails 3.2.6 app and in this app I got users, events and checkins.
I am also using Postgres.

**User**

```
has_many :events

has_many :checkins
```

**Events**

```
belongs_to :user

has_many :checkins
```

**Checkins**

```
belongs_to :user

belongs_to :event
```

When I call for all checkins that a user has made (using the code below) I also want
to get all basic data for the events that the checkins is attached too but it does not work.
I only get the data for the checkin and nothing about the event. What is wrong?

```
current_user.checkins.includes(:event)
```

I tried this too:

```
current_user.checkins.joins(:event)
```

**UPDATE**

I did this to get all event data instead of checkin data. Is this a correct
way of doing it?

```
checkins = current_user.checkins

@array = Array.new

@array = checkins.collect {|checkin| checkin.event}

render :json => {:results => @array}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong with `current_user.checkins.includes(:event)`, but you might be expecting something different than what Rails is supposed to do. In order to access each event, you will need to do so through the checkin. Here's an example of something you might do:

```
checkins = current_user.checkins.includes(:event)
checkins.each do |checkin|
  puts "I'm at the event: #{checkin.event}"
end
```

Comment: Looks good! Basically what I need to achieve is to get all the event data instead of the checkin data for each "checkin" and return it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is a has many through relationship. Add this to the user model (after you've declared the checkins association)

```
has_many :checked_in_events, :through => :checkins, :source => :event
```

Then you can do

```
current_user.checked_in_events
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Is it the user model that should have this?

Comment: But will that not be a bad thing. The user should be able to have events that he created himself AND be able to checkin to other peoples events?

Comment: Oops, forgot you had another events association. updated my answer.